# Which option would be better for historical information of a table?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a table A where I store information that my users can update, but because of the users requirement I need to keep track of the changes in the info. 
Considering that:

- This info will be display whenever the user wants to
- The info could be changed anytime but not so often, let's say 5    times a year

I tought of some options like:

- Store all the records (olds and new ones) in a single table
- Create 2 tables A and B, one (A) that keeps just the current   record, and   another one (B) with the not current ones. In this   case I would do an insert in B with the new information and then   I would do an update to A.

I like the second option more than the first, but I'm not sure if the second is really the solution, or just a fancy way to do it, cause at the end I'm storing the same amount of data right?

Does anyone have other options, or how do you face this kind of situation when developing?

Thank you very much!

Azu

Comment: With the limited details provided, the only reasonable answer is "Depends".

Comment: We use both of those methods in different places where I work.  Personally, I prefer the first one, with effective/end dates attached to each record so it's easy to tell when it was changed.  It's a little easier to query if you need to know which records were valid on a given, non-current, date.  Depends on how big/frequently changing your data is, though, and how often you will need to view the history - it might get out of hand quickly.

Comment: @APH and it's sometimes not too much trouble when adding a new record to maintain a "this is the current record" flag, and to remove it from the previous current record.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to convert the table to version normal form (vnf). You say this table contains data users may update. I infer from that there is an independent primary table consisting of static data with the PK of the updatable table also a FK to the independent table.

```
create table Versions(
    ID        int not null,
    ModDate   date not null,
    ModUserID int not null,
    ...     ..., -- data fields
    constraint PK_Versions primary key( ID, ModDate ),
    constraint FK_Versions_Primary foreign key( ID )
        references Primary( ID ),
    constraint FK_Versions_User foreign key( ModUserID )
        references Users( ID )
);
```

Versioning doesn't require the FK reference back to the primary, I just included it for illustration. But it does show why I call it "version normal form." You will be normalizing changeable data from the static data. This way, standard normalizing techniques apply.

Most queries will probably be only interested in the "current" version of each entity. The current version is the most recent one -- the one with the largest modification date.

```
select  *
from    Versions v
where   v.ModDate =(
        select  Max( v1.ModDate )
        from    Versions v1
        where   v1.ID = v.ID );
```

Don't let the subquery worry you. I have used versioning for years and the query is quite fast.

If there is a primary table, the join to show the entire current tuple is based on the query above.

```
select  p.*, v.* -- You will want to expand these out
from    Primary p
join    Versions v
    on  v.ID = p.ID
    and v.ModDate =(
        select  Max( v1.ModDate )
        from    Versions v1
        where   v1.ID = v.ID );
```

In fact, if you make a view of the first query, the second query could just join to that view. Also don't worry about joining to simple views. If you examine the execution plans of the full query and a join to the view, they should be the same.

You could also have a view made from the second query, exposing only the current versions of the entire entity. If there is a lot of data -- many versions of many entities -- a `select * from view` will be noticeably slower than a similar dump of a table consisting of only current rows. However, if you filter the data -- `select * from view where ID = 12345` -- the results should be similar.

But here is where the power of this design becomes clear. Suppose you wanted to know the version of an entity at some particular point in the past. The query is not significantly different. Consider the first query:

```
select  *
from    Versions v
where   v.ModDate =(
        select  Max( v1.ModDate )
        from    Versions v1
        where   v1.ID = v.ID
            and v1.ModDate <= :DateOfInterest );
```

Just the addition of `and v1.ModDate <= :DateOfInterest` to the subquery allows you to look back in time to see what the data looked like on any particular date and time.

My typical implementation is to have a "current" view that shows only the current version of each entity and a "history" view which shows all versions. All DML goes thru the "current" view. An "instead of" trigger translates each operation into the actual operations needed to maintain the versioned data. For example, UPDATE would become an INSERT of a new version which would, of course, become the new current version for that entity.

Comment: I've found your VNF answers fantastic - thank you for the time and care you put in, much respect.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally go for the latter, unless I had a partitioning method available that could keep all of the current records in their own set of partitions.

The reason is that otherwise you end up with current and old records co-mingled in the same data blocks, which reduces the efficiency of your caching because the old records are generally not required very often.

If you went for the former method I would flag "current" versions of records to make it trivially easy to find them through an index.

However that can also affect the query optimiser's estimations of expected cardinalities. If it sees that 20% of rows are "current" and 5% of rows have some date (last_transaction?) in the last month, it might infer that 1% of current rows have a date in the last month, whereas the actual figure could be higher than 20%.

On balance, if the historical records are infrequently required as part of normal application activity, I'd bump them off to a dedicated table.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to use a current indicator flag as this impacts greatly the semantics and understanding of what a row represents.  Each row should represent a distinct entity in the world.  When adding a current indicator each row now **might** represent a single entity, or it might represent a **version** of that entity's characteristics for a period of time.  Querying this table now becomes more complex and error prone.

But before designing a history table, check to see if your DBMS provides any temporal features.  For example, [DB2](http://www.ibmbigdatahub.com/blog/temporal-tables-db2) supports creating temporal tables which can track history automatically for you.  [SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn935015.aspx) and [Oracle 12c](http://www.dbanotes.com/oracle-database/oracle-12c-temporal-database/) now also support temporal tables.  Another option is to see if your DBMS provides a change data capture option which can be configured to capture every change and write it to a replica.  [Oracle Golden Gate](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/data-integration/goldengate/overview/index.html), [SQL Server Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb522489(v=SQL.105).aspx), and [IBM Change Data Capture](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibminfochandatacapt) work this way.